# Is there a way to store data in JavaScript/EcmaScript in Minecraft?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, minecraft

I'm trying to make a Private Minecraft Bedrock Edition Realm/Server and want to store the users data so i can access it even when the Server is offline for rework or changes but I don't know how, can anyone help me?

To clarify my question, is there a way to save something like a object or array in my case that got modified while the code was running so when i reolaunch the code it still has the state it had when i modified it and not the state it has default

Here is a Example to how i mean this

```js
import {world} from '@minecraft/server' // The minecraft Module
let players = []; // This is where i want to store the players data

world.events.tick.subscribe((data) => { // This function gets executed 20 times a second (every minecraft tick)
    let onlinePlayers = Array.from(world.getPlayers()) // All Online Players

    onlinePlayers.forEach((onlinePlayer) => { // Pushes every Player to the array

        let player = { // This is the stored Player
            name: onlinePlayer.name, // Player Name
            data: {
                location: onlinePlayer.location, // Location
                dimension: onlinePlayer.dimension, // Dimension
                tags: onlinePlayer.getTags() // Players Ranks and Tags
            }
        }
        players.push() // Pushes the Player to the Array
    })
})

// Filters old Player data and sets it to the new one so no duplicates get created
const filteredPlayers = [...new Map(players.map((m) => [m.name, m])).values()];
players = filteredPlayers
```

So i want the `${players}` Array to have the Players that got stored inside even when i close the Server or Restart it

Edit: for everyone who didn't relize that i tagged es6 and that this code is obviously not node.js. This code does **NOT** support any kind of node.js modules, node.js syntax or any node.js only feature

Comment: The ECMAScript specification doesn't include any feature for input/output. It's dependant on the host environment for that. Presumably, if you've got this far, there's some developer documentation for whatever runtime you are using that you could check.

Comment: How do you run this code? Is this a minecraft mod? A plugin? Or maybe it just runs locally on your pc?

Comment: This is for the Minecraft Bedrock Edition. It runs locally on your World and uses the integrated Minecraft "Gametest API", but many browser features like .fetch() and XMLHttpRequest don't work/dont exist(they are like an empty var so when you call them they are undefined)

Comment: Also it only allows you to import .js and .d.ts files, not .json(idk if thats just esm)